# Where is the Catalogues of Enlightenment from?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

Where can I find the Catalogues of Enlightenment touchstone combo?

Answer (score 6):

A quick search on this very site, gives the answer ([in someone else's question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/86430/catalogues-of-enlightenment-whats-a-creatures-cleric-level-when-it-has-none))

> The touchstone site Catalogues of Enlightenment (Planar Handbook 166-7)...

Answer (score 6):

The *Planar Handbook* describes the touchstone site Catalogues of Englightenment (166-7).

The *Planar Handbook* describes the feat Planar Touchstone (41-2), but it's also available [free here](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ex/20040706a&page=2). Technically, the *Magic of Incarnum* version of the feat Planar Touchstone (207) supersedes the *Planar Handbook* version except in campaigns where the *Planar Handbook* is considered a [primary source](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/56771/8610) for such topics. It doesn't really matter: the *PlH* and *MoI* feats are functionally identical; the *PlH* version provides more information, though.

Interestingly (to me, anyway), while the feat Planar Touchstone has as a prerequisite Knowledge (the planes) 8 ranks, the *Sandstorm* feat Touchstone (53) has as a prerequisite *either* Knowledge (local) 8 ranks *or* a 250-gp touchstone key, making the later-published feat Touchstone available at level 3 in all but the stingiest-with-the-gp campaigns.

The only difference between the two feats is that the *Planar Handbook* feat Planar Touchstone requires the creature to attune initially to an *extraplanar* touchstone site and the *Sandstorm* feat Touchstone requires the creature to attune initially to a Material Plane touchstone site. This distinction ends upon the creature attuning to a *second* site (replacing the initial site), and the two feats can be used interchangeably thereafter—that is, a later site can be extraplanar *or* a Material Plane site, as the feat's possessor desires and depending on the campaign's availability of appropriate keys to break.

(There's a minor (and perhaps unintentional) difference between *PlH* extraplanar and *Sa* Material Plane touchstone sites in that a creature possessing the feat, on the creature's *first* visit to a Material Plane site, must meet a Material Plane site's recharge conditions to gain the Material Plane site's higher-order ability (making *re*charge a bit of a misleading term), yet a planar touchstone site grants the creature its higher-order ability *automatically* upon the creature's arrival at the site, making *actually* *re*charging the higher-order ability requiring the creature to meet the site's recharge conditions. I assume this is because the *Sandstorm* feat is available earlier, but it could just as easily have been an accidental change.)

Some official free planar touchstone sites are available [here](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20040730a). In addition to those and other touchstone sites in the *Planar Handbook*, *Magic of Incarnum*, and *Sandstorm*, there's a touchstone site buried in *Champions of Valor*—Darkmaiden’s Leap (133)—and *Secrets of Sarlona*—the complicated *Teeth of the Three* (142-3, 145). (They're both terrible, but if you gotta catch 'em all…)

Finally, while the Catalogues are sexy, don't neglect the fact that a creature *can* take the feat Planar Touchstone *et al.* multiple times. Look hard at the other touchstone sites higher-order abilities. Oft neglected are those like Empyrea Mere (*PlH* 155), its higher-order ability one of the game's best low-level methods of healing (assuming the PCs can travel reliably somehow to Celestia), and Echolost (*PlH* 168-9), its higher-order ability granting briefly the creature a burrow speed, a necessity for gods and high-level monsters so they aren't buried forever by canny PCs who, instead of fighting them, just bury them in [cave-ins and collapses](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/wildernessAndEnvironment.html#collapses). (By the way, so far as I'm aware, [the rules don't say a creature can't](https://xkcd.com/1552/) just attune to the Catalogues multiple times by taking Planar Touchstone multiple times, but this DM wouldn't allow that; I mean, seriously, the Catalogues *already* allow any creature with a high enough Wisdom score to cast *one* domain's 9th-level spell—[maybe even as a spell-like ability or supernatural ability](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/86430/8610)—, and that should be enough to make *anyone* happy. Getting *more than one*? That's the greed talkin', man.)

Anyway, the feats Planar Touchstone and Touchstone are *extremely* versatile, and, in this guy on the Internet's opinion, some of the game's best feats, creating for the character a need to adventure and rewarding that adventure appropriately.