# How do domain powers that reference cleric levels work for a non-cleric that gains a domain?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-levels, domains

I'm familiar with what happens when a non-cleric acquires a domain (spell-wise - they don't get domain slots but can add the domain spell to their list and may only cast that spell 1/day). But what level do they count as regarding domain abilities?

For example, the [Travel Domain](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spellLists/clericDomains.htm#travelDomain)'s granted power says (bold for emphasis mine):

> For a total time per day of 1 round per **cleric level** you possess, you can act normally regardless of magical effects that impede movement as if you were affected by the spell *freedom of movement*. This effect occurs automatically as soon as it applies, lasts until it runs out or is no longer needed, and can operate multiple times per day (up to the total daily limit of rounds).

So, hypothetically, let's say a 12th-level druid/wizard/whatever gains this domain (through a prestige class). How many rounds of free movement do they get?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe answers to this question will help folks answer this similar (but not duplicate) question: [Catalogues of Enlightenment: What's a creature's cleric level when it has none?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/86430/8610)

Comment: Doesn't Complete Divine have rules for this?

Comment: @J.Mini *CD* says what happens when a noncleric gains a domain with regards to spells, but, so far as I'm aware, *CD* doesn't cover what happens regarding the domain's granted power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## I’m afraid, they would get zero rounds of free movement.

If the granted power is connected to the number of cleric levels a character possesses and you have none, you can’t activate the power and cannot use it.

What supports this view is this:
The *seeker of the misty isle prestige class (complete divine, 61)* gives you the travel domain as an extra domain at 1st level. The sample seeker of the misty isle on page 62 shows the stats of a ranger 2/cleric 3/seeker of the misty isle 4 built. This character can use the freedom of movement granted power for up to 3 rounds/day - so it’s only the cleric levels that count. The levels of the prestige class through which the travel domain was actually gained are not added.

Unfortunately,  in the chapter *Extra Domains (complete divine, 20)* which provides information on how it works if a noncleric enters a prestige class that allows access to a domain, nothing is said about this particular question.

---

*As Hey I Can Chan points out (see comment below), this sample character gives a hint on how it should be ruled. It’s not an actual rule.*

Comment: This is a good find. Still, while sample characters can be useful, they're often—in fact, I'd say usually—somehow incorrect, and the answer may want to acknowledge this. (A quick glance, for instance, shows, I think, that this sample character's hp are misfigured (too high by 1), it's grapple bonus is wrong (too low by 1), and that its attacks don't include the benefit of its magic weapon.) Further, examples aren't rules, though an example (if accurate) can be used to help determine a rule's meaning; the answer may want to mention this, too. Again, though, nice find. Thanks for digging it up.

Comment: (Also, out of curiosity, why use an [acute accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent) instead of an [apostrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe) for apostrophes?)

Comment: @Hey I Can Chan accent/apostrophe - bad habit, actually. In German language, we don’t use apostrophes that often. :)